# Pregunta de Listas Simples en JAVA!

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy usando dos nodos en un lista simple; el primer nodo es la cabeza y el segundo es el fin. El fin tiene el propósito de almacenarme el último nodo en la lista para que la próxima vez cuando ingrese un dato nuevo no tenga que empezar un recorrido desde el inicio.

En la línea -----AQUÍ----- de `ListaSimple` que paso con la información que tenía la variable, yo la reescribo pero ahora ¿quién apunta a esta nueva información?

```
public class ListaSimple <E>{
    private NodoSimple<E> cabeza, cola;

    public ListaSimple(){}

    public void insertar(E informacion) {
        NodoSimple nuevo = new NodoSimple(informacion);
        if(!esVacia()) {
            cola.setSiguiente(nuevo); 
            cola = nuevo; // -----AQUÍ-----
        }
        else {
            cabeza = nuevo;
            cola = nuevo;
        }
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    public Boolean esVacia(){
        return cabeza==null;
    }
    public String toString(){
        NodoSimple aux = cabeza;
        String informacion = "";
        while(aux != null){
            informacion += aux.getInfo() + "-";
            aux = aux.getSiguiente();
        }
        return informacion;
    }

    public NodoSimple getCabeza(){
        return cabeza;
    }
    public NodoSimple getCola(){
        return cola;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cola debería apuntar ahora a la nueva posición de memoria. En java los objetos son referencias a memoría. Lo que agregaria es NodoSimple<E> nuevo = new NodoSimple<>(informacion).

Comment: Aaaa espero aver entendido, entonces el toda la informacion del objeto anterior quedo almacenado en una direccion de memoria, pero en la primera insercion las variables "cabeza & cola" que hacen referencia a la direccion de memoria del objeto "nuevo" pierden sus datos ya que al salir del metodo la variable "nuevo" no existe porque esta confinada al metodo.                                                                                          
                                                                                                       
Muchas gracias brother

Comment: La variable cabeza siempre va a quedar apuntando a la primera posición de memoria que pediste cuando la lista estaba vacía. Luego el dato que vas modificando es la variable cola. Cuando no esta vacía, modificas cola diciendo que el siguiente va a apuntar al nuevo, y luego a cola le asignas una posición de memoria nueva, por lo que apunta al ultimo.

Comment: muchas gracias!